# Email queue won't send - No disc space left (running Centos 6.3)

Tags: centos, email, exim, queue, tmp

I hope anyone can help me out with the following issue. I'm no longer receiving emails because they are getting stuck in the email queue.

I've tried the following:

1. System reboot (even between the steps below)
2. Clearing temp files using: find /tmp -cmin +720 -exec rm {} \;
3. Clearing all temp files
4. exim -qf
5. exim -qff

With the last two commands, the commands couldn't finish executing.

I really hope someone can help me out. If it helps, this is a log file saying no space left on device

```
2013-08-09 19:57:29 1V6vjZ-00014J-9U == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092649.H84616P5755.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
2013-08-09 19:57:47 1V7p0b-0004pC-W8 == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092667.H428517P5853.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
2013-08-09 19:58:05 1V7dH3-0001zg-QZ == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092685.H780135P5879.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
2013-08-09 19:58:24 1V7Ud3-0003Ad-54 == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092704.H156764P5948.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
2013-08-09 19:58:24 1V7vQ6-0003Wi-Di Unfrozen by forced delivery
2013-08-09 19:58:25 1V7vQ6-0003Wi-Di ** email@removed.com F=<> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<email@removed.com>: host 613.cl [74.220.202.15]: 550 No Such User Here
2013-08-09 19:58:25 1V7vQ6-0003Wi-Di Frozen (delivery error message)
2013-08-09 19:58:43 1V7lbg-0001k7-W8 == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092723.H857798P6030.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
2013-08-09 19:59:02 1V7mhg-0005vo-Ir == email@removed.com <email@removed.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery defer (28): No space left on device: failed to open tmp/1376092742.H190957P6124.web.ghservers.org (10 tries)
```

Comment: Their is enough space on all partitions. (Friend of Peter van Dam)

Comment: Can you please show the output of `df`

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the problem is solved. The inodes were full. The cookie folder seemed to have so many files that more files couldn't be added. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check Exim queue by:

  ```
  exim -bp
  ```
- Clean, If you have many Frozen or very old mail in queue:

  ```
  exim -q
  ```
- Move Queue to another partition, has more disk space,
- Set time limit for frozen or bounced mail:

  ```
  # vi /etc/exim.conf

      timeout_frozen_after = 1d ( 1 Days )
  ```